# Why Aren't Deletes Cascading With This NHibernate Configuration File?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the below NHibernate file, however I am not allowed to delete a Question because of a foreign key constraint on either of the two Answer tables. The desired behavior is to delete Answers once corresponding Questions are deleted and cascade settings are set on the Answers element.

Below is the configuration file, can anyone see what the problem is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="Test.Domain" assembly="Test.Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Question" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <discriminator />
    <property name="Text" length="500" />
    <property name="Note" length="2000" />
    <property name="DateRun" />
    <many-to-one name="ChoiceType" column="ChoiceTypeId" />
    <bag name="Answers" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
      <key column="QuestionId" on-delete="cascade" />
      <one-to-many class="Answer" />
    </bag>
  </class>
  <class name="Answer" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Question" column="QuestionId" />
    <many-to-one name="Group" column="GroupId" />
    <property name="Comment" />
  </class>
  <class name="Choice">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Text" length="500" />
  </class>
  <class name="ChoiceType">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Type" />
    <list name="Choices" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
      <key column="ChoiceTypeId" />
      <list-index column="ChoicesPos" />
      <one-to-many class="Choice" />
    </list>
  </class>
  <class name="Division">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
  </class>
  <union-subclass name="FreeTextAnswer" extends="Answer">
    <property name="Text" length="500" />
  </union-subclass>
  <union-subclass name="MultipleChoiceAnswer" extends="Answer">
    <many-to-one name="Choice" column="ChoiceId" />
  </union-subclass>
  <subclass name="MultipleChoiceQuestion" extends="Question" />
  <subclass name="FreeTextQuestion" extends="Question" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it 
    cascade="all-delete-orphan"

... with a hyphen, as opposed to two enum values?

Answer (score 0):

Your answers collection mapping should look like this:

```
<bag name="Answers" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="QuestionId"/>
  <one-to-many class="Answer" />
</bag>
```

I removed `on-delete="cascade"`. When you you want to remove one answer from the question you will have to 'chase pointers'. Set reference to question to NULL, in addition to removing it from answers collection:

```
answer.Question = null;
```